# deleting massive rows from excel

Tags: windows, excel, csv, ms-office

I have a big csv file opened in EXCEL. I would like to delete all the rows from row 100020 to row 800030. I tried selecting all the rows using mouse, but not quite easy. Are there any easy approaches to do this kind of deleting operation?

Comment: highlight row 100020. scroll down using mouse wheel/scroll bar (not cursor keys - the highlighting should not vanish) to row 800030, and then SHIFT+click to highlight this row and all rows in between

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
Sub deleteRows()
  Rows("100020:800030").Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Place the code in new module file like this:

[image]

Comment: yes, that should be the one that I would like to do. But where to input this kind of command line? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: This is VBA macro in excel.  From developer tab, select VBA and input this into a new module.  Then run (F5).  If you don't have the developer tab goto file, options, customize ribbon and check developer.

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained. :)

Answer (score 3):

Hit Ctrl+G (Go To), In "Reference" box enter $100020:$800030 and hit enter.
This selects the rows. Then do what you need with them: delete, copy, etc.

Comment: I get 'Reference is invalid', Excel 2010, how are you entering it exactly?

Comment: @PortlandRunner: hm, I also use Excel 2010. Does something simpler, like "$2:$5" work? Or "2:5"? Or "B2:C3"? Also, what is your default reference style, A1 or R1C1?

Comment: Smaller numbers work fine.  Looks like anything over 65536 (2^16) is considered invalid for me.  My default reference style is A1.  Interesting...

Comment: Found it... I was in compatibility mode for 07' due to the document I had opened, so the workbook limited my rows.

Comment: + 1 For the non vba method :)

Answer (score -1):

If you have a raw text csv that you imported into Excel, this'll work faster with `sed` (if you have access to a system with `sed`):

```
sed '100020,800030d' my.csv > my_new.csv
```